# Regex match all text except trailing paranthesis with number

Tags: regex, powershell

This is probably easy, but I can't seem to grasp regex properly.
I need to match characters in strings up from start until a paranthesis with a digit inside (if one exists). If the paranthesis is followed by more text the entire string should match.

```
Test string (abc) = match "Test string (abc)"
Test string (abc) test = match "Test string (abc) test"
Test string (1) = match "Test string"
Test string (1) Test = match "Test string (1) Test"
```

I have this but it don't care whats inside the paranthesis so only match "Test string" no matter what.

```
^[^\(\d\)]+
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

EDITED: Added extra test string (#4) to my question and Wictor's regex in the comment matches this as well:
`^.*?(?=\s*\(\d+\)$|$)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are *extracting* with `-match`, you may use

```
^.*?(?=\s*\(\d+\)|$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E.*%3F%28%3F%3D%5Cs*%5C%28%5Cd%2B%5C%29%7C%5Cr%3F%24%29&i=Test%20string%20%28abc%29%0D%0ATest%20string%20%28abc%29%20test%0D%0ATest%20string%20%281%29&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than newline, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\(\d+\)|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with 0+ whitespaces, `(`, 1+ digits, `)` or end of string.

Note you may try a replacing approach with

```
$line -replace '\s*\(\d+\).*'
```

where `\s*\(\d+\).*` matches 0+ whitespaces, `(`, 1+ digits, `)` and then the whole rest of the line with `.*`.

Comment: Wow, fast answer thanks. That will work perfect, thanks.

What if "Test string (1) Test" should also be matched, i.e. only stop before paranthesis with digit if it dont contain something after the paranthesis. Make any sense?

Comment: @Nicolaj I did not notice you edited the comment. If you have another question, you should post a new question, or edit the current one. Your "what-if" is not clear. As per the question, `Test string` is matched. Probably you mean [something like](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%3f%28%3f%3d%5cs*%5c%28%5cd%2b%5c%29%5cr%3f%24%7c%5cr%3f%24%29&i=Test+string+%28abc%29%0d%0aTest+string+%28abc%29+test%0d%0aTest+string+%281%29+Test%0d%0aTest+string+%281%29&o=m) `^.*?(?=\s*\(\d+\)$|$)`

Comment: Thanks Wictor, question amended - both your regex'es works as propsed, the last one is also perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nicolaj Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.